# Electromagnetic field of a point charge seen from a rotating reference frame

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, reference-frames, rotation, point-particles

Let us consider a point charge sitting in the origin of our coordinate system. If we change to a rotating system, will the field  of the point charge still look the same? Intuitively I would say yes, however when I write down the wave equation

$
g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu} A_{\sigma} = J_{\sigma}
$

there appear some extra terms that suggest that the vector potential changes due to the rotation.

Comment: Sorry but why would you expect the field to remain unchanged? The field changes when viewed even from different inertial frames of reference. So my intuition would be that the field should change when viewed from a non inertial frame too. My second guess would be that this transformation must involve GR.

Comment: @Apoorv Khurasia: You do not need GR since spacetime remains flat, but you will need to consider more complex coordinates and world-lines than the simple 'square' grid of the Lorentz transformations. I would say that you will need Differential Geometry rather than Linear Algebra (which covers most of the the SR).

Comment: @Cryo True, what I meant was that the metric tensor won't be diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the four-vectors. Assuming the charge is itself not accelerating, simply find its field in its own inertial rest frame.

$\mathbf{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\,\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}$

Then stick this into the electromagnetic tensor: $F^{i0}=-F^{0i}=\left(\mathbf{E}/c\right)^i$, $F^{ab}=0$

and then boost this tensor into your instantaneous rest-frame, i.e. the intertial frame where the temporal axis is instantaneously tangent to your world-line.

You will find that this electromagnetic field will not satisfy the *conventional* Maxwell's Equations, but it is to be expected since Maxwell's Equations will change once we start considering non-inertial motion. What I mean is that non-inertial observer will be able to deduce that he/she is not in inertial motion by seeing that electromagnetism seems to be obeying different laws. The laws for the charge in inertial motion, however, will remain 'normal'.